# Linking returns error for custom installed libcurl library on Debian

Tags: libcurl

I am working a Debian system running Stretch and building with g++. The latest Debian [libcurl package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libcurl4-openssl-dev) is of libcurl version 7.38.0. I am trying to implement multipart form post by following [this sample](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html); it uses [curl_mime_init](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_mime_init.html) which was added in libcurl version 7.56.0. I custom installed the latest version of the library and I am able to initialise a curl object but the linker returns an error for curl_mime_init().

```
#include<iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   CURL *curl;
   curl_mime *form = NULL;

   curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
   curl = curl_easy_init();

   if(curl) 
      form = curl_mime_init(curl);
}
```

I didn't install the library in the proper /usr/local folder. The program is built with

```
g++ test.cpp -o test 
-I/home/Documents/curl-master/include 
-L/home/Documents/curl-master  -lcurl
```

The sample says that the exact code has not been verified to work. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think perhaps it's your non-standard install location that's to blame.  If I build the same library on Ubuntu (so that's g++ version`(Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0`) but I don't install it (so I just do `configure` and `make`) and then build the test with reference to that:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -I/home/fin/Desktop/curl-7.61.0/include -L/home/fin/Desktop/curl-7.61.0/lib/.libs  -lcurl
```

then it links fine.

I should note that I didn't pass *any* parameters to `configure`

Comment: The instructions in the GIT-INFO are to run buildconf, configure, then make. There is no configure file before running buildconf.

Comment: I didn't pull from git, I untarred the 7.61.0 tarball from the libcurl website. That does contain a configure file, and I didn't have to buildconf.

Comment: The problem was not ending the -L library path with lib/.libs

Comment: There is a run-time error: 'symbol lookup error: ./test: undefined symbol: curl_mime_init'

Comment: If libcurl wasn't found on your library path, you would have had a linker error saying it couldn't find libcurl, not that it couldn't find that specific symbol. 

As it's finding the library, but not that symbol, that shows its finding a library that doesn't have that symbol.  So presumably it's picking up a system-wide libcurl.so or libcurl.a

You can *force* gcc to use a specific library by passing it the library name explicitly:

    g++ test.cpp -o test /home/foo/bar/libcurl.so

Comment: With the above syntax pointing to the .so file , the program doesn't build because of the new functionality.

Comment: this also returns the run-time error: g++ test.cpp -o test -I/home/pi/Desktop/curl-7.61.0/include /home/pi/Desktop/curl-7.61.0/lib/.libs/libcurl.so